# using pluck on nested results in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a query that returns the following results.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#5145
  all: [
    App\Models\Result {#5207
        id: 198,
        result_id: 30,
        result_type: "App\Models\Touchpoint",
        audit_id: 1,
        weight: 7,
        pics: 0,
        recs: 0,
        rating: 4,
        comments: "none",
        complete: 1,
        created_at: "2022-06-03 03:42:24",updated_at: "2022-06-03 03:42:24",
        result: App\Models\Touchpoint {#5210
            id: 30,
            name: "Lineman",
            description: "The location food offer was available on Lineman",
            sort_order: 25,
            req_pics: 0,
            req_recs: 0,
            sector_id: 1,
            created_at: null,
            updated_at: "2022-04-02 14:02:34",
        },
    },
    App\Models\Result {#5119
        id: 199,
        result_id: 29,
        result_type: "App\Models\Touchpoint",
        audit_id: 1,
        weight: 7,
        pics: 0,
        recs: 0,
        rating: 4,
        comments: "none",
        complete: 1,
        created_at: "2022-06-03 03:43:38",
        updated_at: "2022-06-03 03:43:38",
        result: App\Models\Touchpoint {#5206
            id: 29,
            name: "Grab",
            description: "The location food offer was available on Grab",
            sort_order: 24,
            req_pics: 0,
            req_recs: 0,
            sector_id: 1,
            created_at: null,
            updated_at: "2022-04-02 14:02:26",
        },
    },
  ],
}
```

This is the query I'm using to get that collection and I want the result to just contain sort_order, name, description, rating and weight from these results and place them in an array.  I'm assuming I need to use pluck to get the correct fields but when I try to pluck 'result.name', etc. I get told result doesn't exist.

```
$result = Result::query()->where('audit_id', 1)->where('result_type', 'App\Models\Touchpoint')->whereIn('result_id', $tps)->with('result')->get();
```

This needs to be in a query without manipulating the collection as I need to feed it into Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets, which requires a query not the query results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eager load constraints

```php
$result = Result::query()
    ->where('audit_id', 1)
    ->where('result_type', 'App\Models\Touchpoint')
    ->whereIn('result_id', $tps)
    ->with('result:id,sort_order,name,description')
    ->select('id', 'result_id', 'rating', 'weight')
    ->get();
```

If you want to remove the nesting and flatten the result set you can `map()` over the collection

```php
$result->map(function($item) {
    $item['sort_order'] = $item->result->sort_order;
    $item['name'] = $item->result->name;
    $item['description'] = $item->result->description;

    //remove the nested relation
    $item->unsetRelation('result');
})
->toArray();

/**
 * Will return something like
 [
    [
        'id' => 198,
        'result_id' => 30,
        'rating' => 4,
        'weight' => 7,
        'sort_order' => 25,
        'name' => 'Lineman',
        'description' => 'The location food offer was available on Lineman'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 199,
        'result_id' => 29,
        'rating' => 4,
        'weight' => 7,
        'sort_order' => 24,
        'name' => 'Grab',
        'description' => 'The location food offer was available on Grab'
    ]
]
*/
```

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent Relationships - Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: that gives me ('id', 'result_id', 'rating', 'weight') in the result but I can see no way to include 'sort_order', 'name', 'description' in the result from there?

Comment: @AaronHarker Have updated answer - please check whether my understanding about your desired output is okay and your expected/desired output matches

Comment: Sorry that was my bad, I left out the fact that I need a query not a collection to give to another class.  I've revised my question to explain.

Comment: OK I just realized the Excel class actually allows me to apply mapping to the query results so your answer has gotten me going.  Thanks for making me think of an alternative.

Comment: @AaronHarker That's great. Just for info, if you require to get query instead of the results/array then may have to go the query builder way using **join**  to merge the columns from the two tables for a single output